# MVC Sitemap - conditionally display description

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I am using MVC Sitemap provider for my site, and I show up to three versions of the navigation on my page at a time.

First, the top level:

`@Html.MvcSiteMap("MvcSiteMapProvider").Menu(0, true, false, 1)`

Sub sections, which is reused when viewing a top-level page:

`@Html.MvcSiteMap("MvcSiteMapProvider").Menu(2, 1, true)`

Here is a 2 level section in my sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Bid Manager" description="This is an example of a section description" controller="Bid" action="Index" icon="&#x28;">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Create / Edit Sale Event" description="This is an example of a section description" controller="Bid" action="Manage" icon="&#x29;" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Bidding Status Manager" description="This is an example of a section description" controller="Bid" action="Status" icon="&#x5d;" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

...and here is the display template

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel
```

@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@{
    // Defaults
    string itemIcon = "1";
    string listClass = "menu-item";

```
// Pick up options in custom parameters
if (Model.MetaAttributes.ContainsKey("icon")) {
    itemIcon = Model.MetaAttributes["icon"].ToString();
}
if (Model.MetaAttributes.ContainsKey("disabled") && (Model.MetaAttributes["disabled"].ToString() == "true")) {
    listClass = "disabled";
    itemIcon = "&#x55;";
}

// Check if this node is active
listClass = (Model.IsCurrentNode || Model.IsInCurrentPath) ? "active" : listClass;


// Show stuff
<li class="@listClass">
<div class="menu-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="@Html.Raw(itemIcon)"></div>
<p>
@if (listClass == "disabled") {
    <span>@Model.Title</span>
}
else {
    <a href="@Model.Url">@Model.Title</a>
}
</p>
<p class="description">@Model.Description</p>
</li>
```

}

I have it so that the display template is identical for each instance of the sub-level navigation with all cosmetic differences via CSS.  What I want to do is conditionally include the description attribute, e.g. only render the description.

Currently, the description is rendered for all menus and then hidden with CSS for those where I don't want it, which is obviously a dirty fix.

This may well be a more broad MVC questions, such as setting a variable before calling the sitemap, then using that variable in the display template.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I fully understand what you want, but can't you just put another condition in your template?

```
@if (listClass == "disabled") {
    <p class="description">&nbsp;</p>
} else {
    <p class="description">@Model.Description</p>
}
```